# Measure width and height of Html element in Dart

Tags: dart

I would like to know the exact size of an element without margin, border and padding, just the width and height of the most inner box (see image below).

Currently i'm aware of the function "getBoundingClientRect" which gives the size including border and padding. There is also the "client" property which returns a Rect including the padding.

So the question is, how do i get the width and height without padding?

[image: CSS box model]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the DOM does not provide such functionality. That's why most libraries like jQuery, ExtJS, etc. provide helper methods. They essentially [parse the style](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L354) and figure it out.

Here's an example:

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #000"></div>
```

```dart
int getWidth(Element element) {
  var paddingLeft = element.style.paddingLeft.replaceAll('px', ''); // You may want to deal with different units.
  var paddingRight = element.style.paddingLeft.replaceAll('px', '');

  return element.clientWidth - int.parse(paddingLeft) - int.parse(paddingRight);
}
```

And the usage:

```dart
print(getWidth(query('#test')));
```

Result:

```
100
```

Notes:

- You might consider dealing with different types of units (px, pt, em, ...).
- The `box-sizing` property also has an effect you might want to check for.

If I or you happen to find the time, perhaps release a Pub package or something. :)

Comment: was the package released? =]

Answer (score 2):

This pub package can predict the size of a *text* (without margin, border and padding) that does not yet exist in the DOM: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/textent

Answer (score 1):

Try the relatively recently introduced [Element.contentEdge](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Element#id_contentEdge), that seems to be exactly what you want.

[This](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8376#c20) comment from a Google employee lists some more related methods that has also been added. Note that at least some of them are still marked as *Experimental* in the API docs, but they can be useful nonetheless.